# Priority incorrect on CSS inline class

Tags: php, css, inline

If you look at [**this *CssToInlineStyles* class**](https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles/blob/master/css_to_inline_styles.php) on github. It is essentially trying to make CSS all inline. However, it has priority all wrong when it comes to the already inline CSS being overwritten by the definitions in the style block!

I think on [line 312](https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles/blob/master/css_to_inline_styles.php#L312) I need to put in a condition to make sure the inline styles already present should never be overwritten by any definition in the CSS properties. But it looks like it isn't that easy!

Any ideas? I've tried contacting the owner of the class, no reply. If I fix this, I'll make a pull request on github.

### Update

If you have the following in a style block:

```
p{font-family:Arial;font-size:0.9em;color:#53534a;} 
.webv {font-size: 10px; padding:5px 0 0 150px}
```

Then if you have a p tag like so:

```
<p class="webv" >Testing</p>
```

Then the class `.webv` needs to take effect in terms of `font-size`.

### Update 2

Hakre's solution works well but there is one case it doesn't work. For example if you have this style block:

```
  *{padding:0;margin:0;}
  h1{padding-bottom:10px;}
```

The padding for the h1 is still 0, the second h1 doesn't take over which it should! So it looks like this:

```
<h1 style="padding:0; margin:0;">Test</h1>
```

Comment: Please add the style attribute output for the h1 element for the update 2 as well.

Comment: I have added what it looks like after. It just completely ignores the `padding-bottom` in the h1 definition! Btw, due to fixing something else I am making use of `$properties = array_reverse($properties, true);` just after line 312.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately the owner of this class has fixed this issue! The updated class can be found [here](https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to have them overwritten you first need to obtain the existing properties from the HTML source.

You then can either check if those are already set before setting the new to prevent overwriting, or you just overwrite them later on to the default ones.

As existing properties are already extracted before, it might work as:

```
foreach($rule['properties'] as $key => $value)
    if(!isset($properties[$key])) $properties[$key] = $value;
```

(this will overwrite `NULL` properties, in case it's a problem, use `array_key_exists` instead of `isset`).

You should add a flag to the class/function to change the behavior, so the current behavior does not break but you make your needs optional.

**Edit:** As multiple rules can apply, the next rule will not overwrite something of the previous rule (which it should but is prevented by the edit above), so this needs more control to preserve the original properties:

```
$originalProperties = $properties;
foreach($rule['properties'] as $key => $value) $properties[$key] = $value;
$properties = $originalProperties + $properties;
```

**Edit 2:** The second suggestion won't work as well. Basically there is need to get the very original values because that function changes the style attribute while it iterates over rules and elements. The same element can become modified twice, so the `$originalProperties` are not really the original properties but can be modified ones.

*Maybe* this works with [`spl_object_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) to create a consistent id/key for each element, but I'm not sure. Maybe DomElement offers something comparable internally, but I have not found such (which should fit better). With a specific key/id per each concrete element, only on first appearance, the very original properties can be preserved:

```
$elementId = spl_object_hash($element);
if(!isset($originalProperties[$elementId]))
{
    $originalProperties[$elementId] = $properties;
    $originalElements[$elementId] = $element; // Needed to make spl_object_hash work
}
foreach($rule['properties'] as $key => $value) $properties[$key] = $value;
$properties = $originalProperties[$elementId] + $properties;
```

Comment: @harke - I could of sworn I made that change. I have no idea why I dismissed it! It is working now, just going to test it a few more times.

Comment: I wonder why the original author didn't do it this way, because by definition, the inline styles have a higher priority than linked / style-element styles. Your use-case makes sense to me. Maybe you need to give the original author more time to reply? Might be in holidays.

Comment: @harke - please see example in the question. I've updated it. This is the case I am having problems with! He might me on holiday actually, I thought I would attempt to solve it myself and then give him the solution but I found it difficult!

Comment: Which kind of problem, please elaborate.

Comment: What will happen now with the newly added if condition is that the second `font-size` will be ignored even though it has a higher priority.

Comment: okay, there is need to get the original priority list and preserve it, so no quick hack on that line.

Comment: @Abs: Edited the answer. This will preserve the original properties but still set all rule properties as before. But that edit does not correctly reflect the very original state of the element's style attribute. This needs more work as the current design of the function does not at all reflect that case. Basically a hash-map that stores all original styles and then uses those. Could speed up the whole routine as well but memory consumption will increase.

Comment: @Abs: Modified again, it's somehow dirty because it needs to keep all elements in memory, but it then works with DomDocument, Xpath and spl_object_hash.

Comment: @harke - been testing this and there is one issue still that I've been trying to fix. I have added another update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!important` after the CSS definition to make sure it takes priority.

E.g.

```
.yourstyle
{
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: The class will be passed in HTML and CSS. It will then convert all the style blocks into inline CSS. It's not an issue of the CSS property not having any effect, its being over written during the conversion.